# Crystal Reports - Printed field alignment issue

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

We have created a couple reports in VS2008 and since we've converted to 2012 we've run into an issue where the fields look perfect in the designer and in the viewer, but when we print it the fields are all moved. Now it isn't all the same movement either, some items moved down about an inch, others moved up a half inch, some left/right/etc. So to resolve the issue immediately I've opened designer and manually moved the fields so that they look wrong on designer but they print properly. The issue I'm running into now is when I put a field at the very top of the page, it still pushes it down despite all margins being set to zero.

Now I don't like breaking my designer to make it work, so if there is a more permanent solution people are aware of, that would be ideal. But if there is anyway to force this field to be pushed to top of page, that would be an acceptable temp fix.

The nature of our need here is that this prints on a specific insurance form and the fields have to fit in the proper boxes or they are declined.

Thanks in advance,

- Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to recreate the form in VS2012. Something about the conversion process for an 08 file to 12 just would not hold margins at all.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of guidelines in crystal report you can resolve this issue.

you can enable guidelines from File--> option --> in which layout tab
in Design view panel you can select Guidelines.

now you can design your crystal report and set all the fields in touch of guidelines.
remove unnecessary guidelines. you can set your report easily.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I'm not following your suggestion. I don't have file-> Option in VS 2012, now if I right click on the designer and go to design there is a Guideline check box, but that's about it.